# Read & Write Uncompressed Zip Data from an InputStream Java

Tags: java, zip, nio

Currently, I am downloading a jar file from a website, the classes are further processed, but the resources aren't. This means I do not need to decompress when reading from the URL and recompress the resources when writing to a file.

However, given a ZipInputStream there is no method I am aware of to read the zip entry compressed's data and write it directly to a file with NIO. Normally with NIO with files, I can use the Files#copy function to do this, but I am downloading these files from the network, therefor I do not have this luxury.

Essentially, I have a ZipInputStream and an NIO FileSystem for a Zip file, how do I copy *some* (not all) data from this input stream to the file without decompressing and recompressing each entry?

Comment: Post a minimal reproducable code sample. It sounds like you are trying to add performance changes before observing where and what the problems are.

Comment: I have profiled my code, so I do know that this is an issue. It takes ~20% of the runtime. There is no minimum reproducible code sample because I don't know how to do this in the first place.

Comment: Try splitting up the task: Download the url to file then process it. You may isolate some code section which exhibits or contributes to the problem you observe, to add back to this question.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you are asking here.

### zip to zip

Do you mean: You want to stream a zip file across a network, saving it to the local machine on disk, but only some of the files. You want to do this without actually doing any (de)compression. For example, if the stream contains a zip with 18 files in it, you want to save the 8 files whose name doesn't end in `.class`, but in a fashion that streams the compressed bytes straight from the network into a **zipped** file without any de- or recompression.

In that sense it is equivalent to saving the zip file from network to disk and then attempting to efficiently wipe out some of the entries. Except in one go.

This is a **bad idea**. There are no easy answers here. It is technically possible, with so many caveats that I'm pretty sure you wouldn't want this.

If you need more context as to why that is, scroll down to the end of this answer.

### zip to files

If you just mean: "I want to stream a zip from the network, skipping some of them without decompressing the skipped items or saving them to disk at all (compressed or not), and writing the ones I want to keep straight from network to disk, decompressing them on the fly" - that's simple.

Use `.getNextEntry()` to skip. Treat the `ZipInputStream` as the single entry stream. It EOFs until you move to the next entry, which makes that 'work'.

Here is an example that reads all entries from a zip file, skips all entries that end in `.class`, and writes all the other ones to disk, uncompressing on the fly:

```
public void unpackResources(Path zip, Path tgt) throws IOException {
  try (InputStream raw = Files.newInputStream(zip)) {
    ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(raw);
    for (ZipEntry entry = zip.getNextEntry(); entry != null; entry = zip.getNextEntry()) {
      if (entry.getName().endsWith(".class")) continue;
      Path to = tgt.resolve(entry.getName());
      try (OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(to)) {
        zip.transferTo(to);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`in.transferTo(out)` is the Input/OutputStream equivalent to `Files.copy`. If reads bytes from in and tosses them straight into out until in says that there are no more bytes to give.

---

### Context: Why is zip-to-stripped-zip not feasible?

Compression is extremely inefficient at times if you treat each file in a batch entirely on its own: After all, then you cannot take advantage of duplicated patterns between files. Imagine compressing a database of common baby names, where the input data consists of 1 file per name, and they just contain the text `Name: Joanna`, over and over again. You really need to take advantage of those repeated `Name:`  entries to get good compression rates.

If a compression format does it right, then what you want doesn't really work: You'd have a single table (I'm oversimplifying how compression works here) that maps shorter sequences onto longer ones, but it is designed for efficient storage of the entire deal. If you strip out half the files, that table is probably not at all efficient anymore. If you don't copy over the table, the compressed bytes don't mean anything.

Some compression formats do it wrong and *do* treat each file entirely on its own, scoring rather badly at the 'name files' test. ZIP is, unfortunately, such a format. Which does indeed mean that technically, streaming the compressed data straight into a file / stripping out some files can be done without de/recompressing, assuming a zip file that uses all the usual algorithms (ZIP is not so much an algorithm, it's a container format. However, 99% of the zips out there use a specific algorithm, and many zip readers fail on other zips). Encryption is probably also going to cause issues here.

Given that it's a bit odd, generally libraries for compression just don't offer this feature; it can't be done except, specifically, to common zip files.

You'd have to write it yourself. I'm not sure this is worth doing. De- and recompressing is quite fast (zip was doable 30 years ago. Sprinkle some moore's law over that number and you may get some sense of how trivial it is these days. Your disk will be the bottleneck, not the CPU. Even with fast SSDs).

Comment: My input is guaranteed to be unencrypted, and I have verified with a profiler that de/recompression is an issue (~20% of runtime). I am considering using an external library, I have found a few that give me access to the compressed data, however, integrating it with NIO and my other code is the hard part.

Comment: Are you trying to do the zip-to-zip part, or the zip-to-files part? With NIO, do you mean 'non-blocking I/O', or `java.nio.files`?

Comment: java.nio.files primarily, and I am doing zip-to-zip